# Restoring backup with dd

Tags: linux, backup, restore, dd, ddrescue

I have made a backup of an hard drive using ddrescue. Now I have the .img file. How can I restore the .img Backup to an other hard drive?
I have tried `dd if=backup.img of=/dev/sdc` but the hdd sdc is empty...

Comment: How did you use `ddrescue`?

Comment: sudo ddrescue /dev/sdc backup.img log.log